# Difference in state in Console App between Console.Readline() and setting a break point

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

The following code behaves strange and I try to understand why:

```
NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(8080);
EmbeddableDocumentStore db = new EmbeddableDocumentStore();
db.DataDirectory = @"C:\Google Drive\TradingFramework\RavenDatabase\";
db.UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true;
db.Initialize();

bool halt = true;

Console.WriteLine("Read to try server");
Console.ReadLine();
```

The code above "bool halt" initializes a RavenDB database but I it is irrelevant what it does for the purpose of this question. I ran 2 scenarios:

- a) put a break point in Debug mode within VS2012 at the line `bool halt = true;`. At that point I am supposed to be having access to a created web server listening on localhost:8080. That is not the case. Even putting a wait loop into the code before the break points does not make a difference, nor does a `Thread.Sleep(xxx)`.
- b) I removed the breakpoint and code execution halts and waits for user input at line `Console.ReadLine();`. In this case the server at localhost:8080 responds and works just fine.

Why is that the case? Why is something not executing when I set a break point vs Console.Readline()? Please note I am strictly just testing/developing but I try to understand what difference it makes? I was always under the impression a) and b) is one and the same, it interrupts code execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.Readline()` doesn't break execution, it just waits for input from the user.  Other threads in the application continue to run as normal.

A break-point actually stops execution to allow you to look at the state of the application.  In this state all threads a paused so there's nothing to respond to port 8080.

You could open a command prompt and type `nestat -a`, in which case you should see in either scenario that there's a process listening on port 8080.

Comment: oh yes, how could I have overlooked that. In my case I kick off a server which in this particular case is managed on a thread but in the context of my console application. Stepping into the code should make it hard to respond to any requests ;-) thanks a lot